# Is there an efficient way to upload many documents quickly to the Google Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, asyncstorage

I'm building a game in React Native where users generate cards every 6 seconds or so. These cards are then uploaded to Google Firestore via the Firebase connection that I have set up.

Users generate cards at a rate of 1 every 6 seconds: 1 per 6 seconds = 10 per minute = 600 per hour. Following Google Firebase's default quota of 20,000 free daily writes, I'd exceed the maximum daily allowed with just 34 people on the service for an hour.

To combat this, I've implemented a temporary solution of storing the cards and their data in the user's local storage via AsyncStorage and then uploading it when it "overflows" beyond a certain limit. My code is approximately as follows:

```
// Retrieve the user's inventory.
// Add the new card to the inventory.
// If the inventory length is greater than 15, batch write it all up to Firestore.
```

Is this an efficient and safe way of handling large amounts of data that come quickly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A batch write will **not** help you reduce the number of billed write operations required to write the documents.  A batch write of 5 documents still costs 5 writes, just like you had written them individually.

There is really nothing you can do in this situation except delegate all of the writes to a single entity that is responsible for metering the writes according to whatever limits you specify.  At that point, you are also spending money to make that happen, so you might as well just pay the normal billed rate and save yourself the time and hassle of trying to work around the free limits.  The free limits are there to let you experiment with the product during development, not run a production application.